# Fixed Address-Bar in mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, address-bar

I'm working in a web with hiding scrolls, and I'm having some issues with the address bar in mobile browsers.

I want to use something like this http://www.kuchenbeiser.de/#116 .

In this web both Ios and Android are fixed, but I got no idea how they do it.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
.bkp {
    z-index: 99999;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: where? a div englobing all with class bkp?

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Hey David .bkp{} find your css file and change this